# Can I untick all checklist items in an iOS Notes note?

Tags: ios, notes.app

I've prepared a checklist for air travel with our two kids. Currently everything is ticked but I want to reset it for our next trip. Is there a way to untick everything in one go, or do I have to first go untick every item manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can uncheck checked items in the iOS Notes app using the following hack.

**1. Select the checklist of items you want to be unchecked.**(This can include either checked or unchecked items.)

**2. Remove the check-mark format.** (After doing this, the items should remain selected, which is good.)

**3. Add the check-mark format to the selected items.**

**4. Deselect the items.**

Unfortunately, I haven’t found a more elegant way to do this, but at least it works.

Answer (score 4):

"Select all" text in the list/note.  Right-click and choose "mark as checked".  Click it again to "mark as unchecked".

Comment: Thanks! This is the best answer for working on a Mac desktop, which is what I was looking for! @EJ-Mak answer works for iOS Notes, too, however, doesn't work well with a mixed list (with and without checkmarks). Michelle York's answer works with desktop, and works well with a mixed list (regular body, bulleted, checkboxes, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>

Comment: Was asking for iOS, but this seems to work on Mac. So at least this is a decent workaround.

Answer (score 2):

This became possible natively in iOS 13. From [the docs](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/take-notes-iph1ac0b3a2/ios):

> *Manage items in the list*: Tap the list to see the menu, tap the Show More Items button, tap Checklist, then tap Check All, Uncheck All, Delete Checked, or Move Checked to Bottom.

It only works for contiguous checkboxes, not lists separated by other text. (Credit to [this r/ios post](https://www.reddit.com/r/ios/comments/dgdxqd/unchecking_items_in_notes/f3azarl/) for the lead.)